# DOcloudForbiddenError : limit of 5 jobs total

Tags: optimization, cplex, watson, docplexcloud

I am calling CPLEX model of IBM Watson. It is key from a free account. It has been working well.
But somehow, it slowed down and I stopped my client program. Subsequently, I am getting the following error:
docloud.job.DOcloudForbiddenError: Subscription [ODSTRIAL:502865795] of user  has a limit of 5 jobs total
I tried to abort job by running abort_job(following code), but the jobs are still hanging on and is not letting me run code:

```
import docloud.job
jobClient = docloud.job.JobClient('https://api- 
oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/job_manager/rest/v1/', '<API KEY>')
for job in jobClient.get_all_jobs():
  print(job["_id"])
  jobClient.abort_job(job["_id"])
```

Above code ran; it neither threw any success message nor any failure one.
But jobClient.get_all_jobs() is still throwing details of 5 jobs. And I still get the error DOcloudForbiddenError.

Would be grateful if someone could help in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on the official IBM docplexcloud forum [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/docloud/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete your jobs, the easiest solution is to go to DropSolve to delete the jobs that are blocking your queue:

http://dropsolve-oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/dropsolve

If you look here you will see that it is also possible to delete all jobs using the docplex library:

https://api-swagger-oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/api_swagger/pythondoc/index.html?cm_mc_uid=98978000237415217499350&cm_mc_sid_50200000=17968121523953547432